# Filter table row based on i tag attribute value in 5th td

Tags: jquery

I know there is a ton of examples out there, but nothing seems to work for me and Im going nuts. Here is my code. I have multiple rows, but I want to only show the rows that in the 5th `td` 1st `i` contains the `attr` `stopnotify` and it equals `1` Example (`stopnotify="1"`)

I need to return the entire `tr`

My question is how do I get jquery to filter my table rows and only show rows where in the 5th td and 1st i there is a attr `stopnotify="1"`

**HTML**

```
<tbody class="searchable">
<tr data-index="0" style="display: table-row;">
    <td style="text-align: left; width: 20px; ">1</td>
    <td style="text-align: left; width: 20px; ">testing</td>
    <td style="text-align: left; width: 20px; "><a href="http://www.example.com/" target="_blank">http://www.example.com/</a></td>
    <td style="text-align: left; width: 20px; "> 2 <i class="fa fa-search emailsfound" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="cursor:pointer; color:#397eb9" id="1" title="testing"></i></td>
    <td style="text-align: left; width: 20px; ">0 <i class="fa fa-times-circle stopnotify" client_id="1" stopnotify="1" title="testing" style="cursor:pointer; color:red"></i></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('tbody').addClass('searchable');
$('.stopped_notify').on('click', function() {
    $('.searchable tr').hide();
    $('.searchable tr td:nth-child(5) i').filter(function() {
        return $(this).attr('stopnotify') == 1;
    }).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Here is the jquery

```
$('tbody').addClass('searchable');
$('.stopped_notify').on('click', function() {
    $('.searchable tr').hide();
    $('.searchable tr td:nth-child(5) i').filter(function() {
        return $(this).attr('stopnotify') == 1;
    }).closest('tr').show();
});
```